# Are Hibernate queries vulnerable to SQL injection

Tags: sql, hibernate, sql-injection

I know Hibernate uses prepared statements. But have a doubt when I use `session.createSQLQuery()`.

Is my query safe from SQL injection in this case whether I append the values in the query or use setParameter()

Regards,

Satya

Comment: I hope you are not trying to hack into someones system.

Comment: Never append values in query. Always use parameters. It's as simple as that.

Comment: :) I am trying to hack my own application. So not sure if using `createSQLQuery` is a good idea.

Comment: Yes even if I use parameters, is it safe from SQL injection? all I wanted to know :)

Comment: Not "even if" ... "only if".  SQL injection happens when you append values to the query.  *Appended* values can masquerade as part of the query. On the other hand parameters are (commonly) implemented as part of the protocol right back to the server, so the server so the server itself knows  the difference between the parameters and the query. Therefore parameters can NEVER masquerade as part of the query and are always safe from SQL injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is safe when using `session.createSQLQuery().setParameter()` because hibernate uses parameters then which are safe as JB Nizet and couling said